# SQL Server opendatasource reading a password protected Excel file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms, excel, password

I would like to read a password protected Excel workbook and I'm not sure what the syntax is to enter this parameter.

I found only passwords for the connection, which is not needed due to login.

I use the following in my SQL Server 2014 Web Edition

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa'
select  *
     -- into tr.corelab
        from  OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Data Source=C:\test.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[test$]
```

Comment: Have you tried by adding `;Password=****` to your connection string?

Comment: I don't believe you are able to read from a password protected Excel file using OPENDATASOURCE or even OPENROWSET.  Per [here](https://ciquest.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/sql-server-x64-read-from-excel-openrowset-on-2008-2012-2014-2016/): `Make sure the file you are reading is closed. And no password protection.`

Comment: I tried adding ;Password= but this syntax is related to the windows authenticating and not to excel file. Ok then I'll use VBA or something to remove the password first. thank you for trying.